# Replace null value with 0 or any other value in Android

Tags: android, null

I am developing an Android application and don't know hot to handle null values in calculations in formulas. Here is my code through which I'm trying to skip null value but this is not working.

**Update**

Actually I am trying to do this

```
package ecc.ecc.pkg;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import ecc.ecc.pkg.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ECCActivity extends Activity {
    Button    btncalc;
    EditText  molcostper;
    TextView  costper;
    double    molcost = 0;
    double    cstperusd = 0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initcontrols();
    }
    public void initcontrols()
    {
        molcostper=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.molcostper);
            costper=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.costper);  

        btncalc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalc.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                calculate();
            }

        });
    }
    public void calculate()
    {
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.##");


        molcost=Double.parseDouble(molcostper.getText().toString());


        cstperusd = replaceIfNull(molcost,8500)*94

        costper.setText(formatter.format(cstperusd));
    }
 public static <T> T replaceIfNull(T objectToCheck, T defaultValue) {
          return objectToCheck==null ? defaultValue : objectToCheck;
        }
}
```

this method is genrating error please any one help to handle this

Comment: can you provide us log cat of error.............

Comment: and also oncreate function from start....

Comment: 06-20 11:35:28.269: I/dalvikvm(628): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Comment: "costper" is not initialized with other fields ..

Comment: have you also made changes as per imran in it?...

Comment: Yes I Done same but application stops

Comment: here is recent logcat 06-20 12:00:47.616: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

Comment: would be better if can provide more lines of the log cat like I have attached in my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
if (molcostper != null && !molcostper.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
{   
    molcost=Double.parseDouble(molcostper.getText().toString());
}
else
{
    molcost=8500;
}
```

if it doesn't work then try to download the  '/data/anr/traces.txt' file and check the log. It might provide you some hints. If possible please paste the log here which can help us to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this one point which should be there not complete solution ......

scope of the molcost should be more as there are two molcost `one local to if` `other is in else with greater scope`...

```
double molcost =0;
if (molcostper != null)
        {   
        molcost=Double.parseDouble(molcostper.getText().toString());
        }
        else
        {
        molcost=8500;
            }
result=molcost*10;
```

Comment: Sir Not Working by Initialinzing also same error is displaying and application stops unfortunaltely

Comment: Above in Update I have updated my all code please now check and tell me where is the issue

Comment: would be better if can provide more lines of the log cat like I have attached in my answer....

Answer (score 1):

change your code as:

```
double molcost =0;
EditText molcostperss  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.molcostper);
String change  = molcostperss.getText().toString();
if (change.trim().equals("") && change!=null ) {
 molcost=Double.parseDouble(change);
}
else
{
molcost=8500;

}
result=molcost*10;
```

**EDIT:** update your initcontrols() method by initializing costper as

```
 public void initcontrols()
    {
        molcostper=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.molcostper);
        costper=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.costper);
        btncalc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalc.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                calculate();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: if molcostper is EditText then it should be right............ except this change.trim()!=null and please increase the cope of molcost in if ....

Comment: but i do't known who give me -1 plz leave comment

Comment: even I don't know ............. but I can do one thing as it's look fine for me ..........and let us wait for the user1397781,his satisfaction is more important here...

Comment: imran I have still doubt about this line if (change.trim().equals("") && change.trim()!=null ) {

Comment: importantly  change.trim()!=null is after change.trim().equals("") if change.trim() is so null.equals() will trough the exception

Comment: Sir Using Same Code when I enter nothing in molcostper and press calculate button then application stops unfortunaltely

Comment: Sir I have updated my code please check and verify if any prob exists

Comment: @user1397781 : can u check after replacing  String change  = molcostper.getText().toString(); line by  String change  = "200"; jut test case app is running or not?

Comment: ohh your are missing costper.setText(formatter.format(cstperusd)); here

Comment: costper=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.costper); put it in initcontrols()

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the molcost variable in you code.